# construct and order a list of tuples

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples

Data format in a text,

```
2010-04-16,9:15:00,3450,3488,3450,3470
```

Parse the text,

```
Utuple = collections.namedtuple('Utuple', 'DT,OpenPrice,ClosePrice,HighPrice,LowPrice')
stats = collections.Counter()
for line in data.readlines():
    cols = line.split(',')
    Date = cols[0]
    d = Date.split('-')
    Time = cols[1]
    t = Time.split(':')
    DT = datetime(int(d[0]), int(d[1]), int(d[2]), int(t[0]), int(t[1]), int(t[2]))
    DT = mdates.date2num(DT)
    OpenPrice = float(cols[2])
    HighPrice = float(cols[3])
    LowPrice = float(cols[4])
    ClosePrice = float(cols[5])
    stats[DT] = Utuple(DT,OpenPrice,ClosePrice,HighPrice,LowPrice)
```

I want to get a list of tuples to fit the format of `candlesticks` in matplotlib.finance, which is expected to be

```
  D = [(datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 16, 9, 30), 311, 332, 344, 311), 
   (datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 16, 9, 31), 312, 332, 344, 311), 
   (datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 16, 9, 32), 323, 332, 344, 320),
   (datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 16, 13, 0), 331, 332, 344, 330), 
   (datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 16, 13, 1), 335, 342, 348, 333)]
```

and I did:

```
formated_data = []
for time, index in stats.items():
    formated_data.append(tuple(index))
```

I want to keep this order. But in `formated_data`, it turns out that the lines with `13` in the fourth column in datetime.datetime end up in the front of those with `9`. How to keep the order of the tuples `by the order that I save them` or by `the value of the number (9 < 13)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort the resulting list. The iterator `stats.items()` doesn't guarantee item order.

Alternatively you can iterate the keys via

```
for time in sorted(stats.keys()):
    formatted_data.append(tuple(stats[time]))
```

Comment: thanks. why do the lines with `13` end up in the front of those with `9`? Tuples compare the elements one by one. Is it because `13` is regarded as `string` rather than `int`?

Comment: The order of the `dict.keys()` method is basically random (it depends on the hash value of the key)

Answer (score 2):

**First off an alternative way to parse the text**

```
2010-04-16,9:15:00,3450,3488,3450,3470
```

is essentially

```
date,time,openprice,closeprice,highprice,lowprice
```

and further broken down as

```
YYYY-MM-DD,HH:MM:SS,openprice,closeprice,highprice,lowprice
```

This translates into a regex :

```
r='(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+),(\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)
```

which can be used to generate a tuple

```
tuple = re.search(r, my_date_string).groups()
```

**Your question: Why do items come out in a certain order**

When you insert this into a collection as you have done, this is no longer sorted. Think of this as putting loads of candies into a candy bag. The bag has a black exterior.

What the iterator does is, it takes out one candy at a time. Any preferances that you might have (such as taste, smell, size) do not matter. The only ones that do, is whatever the iterator prefers to output first.

**Re : your comment**

Do you mean that the data you read, is in a different format than what you want it to be, and therefore you want to reorder the tuple to reflect whatever order you find sensible?

*If that's the case*, the regex would remain the same :)
However, you simply assign other indexes to your variables.

This can be done very elegantly in python (prepare to fall in love):

```
date,time,openprice,highprice,lowprice,closeprice = tuple #temporarily store them
tuple = date,time, openprice,closeprice,highprice,lowprice #reorder the tuple
```

*If you think that I've interpreted the original data incorrectly*, then reorder the first of the previous two codelines as needed. I admit that I don't have much knowledge of what kind of application you are making, and therefore have no idea what the different variables mean.

And oh, in case you are wondering how I did this magic, it's quite simple. Comma is a tuple unpacking operator in python.

```
 >>>tuple = ('a', 'b' , 'c')
 >>>first,second,third = tuple
 >>>first
    'a'
```

and so on :)

Comment: This is cute. The only thing is the data is not of the right order. ClosePrice is behind LowPrice in the original data `openprice,highprice,lowprice,closeprice`. Is there any way that to solve this? I want the tuple to be `openprice,closeprice,highprice,lowprice`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is based on a dictionary, which does not preserve order ("A Counter is a dict subclass")

There's [an example in the `collections` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) which shows how to combine the `collections.OrderedDict` and `collections.Counter` which should do what you want:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict


class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
     'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'

     def __repr__(self):
         return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

     def __reduce__(self):
         return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
```

Then just change `stats = collections.Counter()` to `stats = OrderedCounter()`